# Using the prediction from tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used the following code to create a prediction on new data:

```
def predict(dfeval, importedModel):
    colNames = dfeval.columns
    dtypes = dfeval.dtypes
    predictions = []
    for row in dfeval.iterrows():
        example = tf.train.Example()
        for i in range(len(colNames)):
            dtype = dtypes[i]
            colName = colNames[i]
            value = row[1][colName]
            if dtype == "object":
                value = bytes(value, "utf-8")
                example.features.feature[colName].bytes_list.value.extend(
                    [value])
            elif dtype == "float":
                example.features.feature[colName].float_list.value.extend(
                    [value])
            elif dtype == "int":
                example.features.feature[colName].int64_list.value.extend(
                    [value])
    predictions.append(
      importedModel.signatures["predict"](
        examples=tf.constant([example.SerializeToString()])))
    return predictions

val = predict(dfeval, imported)
val
```

which provides:

> [{'predictions': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.24904668]], dtype=float32)>}]

And then I can print the value via:

```
tf.print(val)
```

> [{'predictions': [[0.249046683]]}]

But I want to use the value in a future calculation such as:

```
val + 300
```

Which I would want to have return:

> 300.249046683

But as of now I cannot find a way to extract out and use the prediction.

Comment: Val is not just the value you're looking for, it's a list that contains a dictionary that contains a list of list which has your value in it

Comment: So you just have to extract the value of your prediction from val

Comment: Yes, I get that. I know I wouldn't do 300+val, but instead `actual_val = whatever it takes to get the value out of val` followed by `300+actual_val`. My question around what do I need to do to get to `actual_val` as a float, and not a tensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```py
val[0]['predictions'][0][0]
```

Comment: This allows me to do math on the tensor value, but it's still a tensor, so when I add the value into a dataset, the contents of the cell is presented as: `tf.Tensor(300.24905, shape=(), dtype=float32)`

Comment: You can try the eval function to get the value from the tensor

Comment: I'm not very experienced with tensor flow, but have you tried `float(val[0]['predictions'][0][0])`?

Comment: or `.result()` or `.numpy()`?

Comment: `val[0]['predictions'][0][0].numpy()` worked. Thank you!

Comment: `float(val[0]['predictions'][0][0])` also worked. Thank you!